# Can terminal parameter changes on the slave side be detected on master?

Tags: linux, pty, pseudoterminal

A process (`creator`) creates a pseudo-terminal `master/slave[/dev/pts/1]` pair. Another process (`consumer`) opens `/dev/pts/1` and changes the serial terminal parameters with [`tcsetattr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcflow.3.html).

Is there a way for the `creator` to get the slave parameters once the `consumer` has changed them?

---

<sup>Background for this question comes from wanting to create a multiplexer for a serial terminal. The multiplexer process would consume the serial terminal `/dev/ttyUSB0` and expose multiple slave pseudo-terminals for other application to work with.</sup>